# Do jobs only for merge / specific commit message

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am not quite sure how the gitlab CI workflow should look like to achieve this:

1. In my gitlab repository every feature will be developed in an own branch. At least the branch will be merged to master.
2. I am using npm package grunt-bump to bump up the version of package.json

What I want to do with gitlab CI:

1. For a **merge to master** I want to do some tests (stage test)
2. If test stage has passed successfully, the merge should be done and `grunt bump` should be executed
3. This will bump up the version value and will do a new commit to master. This commit is always tagged like "v0.0.2" and has a message like "Release v0.0.2". Only for this commit I want to go for build stage which will build and deploy the application.

**Summary**

So `grunt bump` should only executed if on master and after successful tests and merging. Only for the resulting commit (Release vx.x.x) the build and deploy job should be done...

Maybe there is a smarter workflow then this idea. Basicly I want to bump version value and tag the commit after merging and successful tests...

**My attempt for YAML-file**

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

lint:
  image: testing:latest
  stage: test
  tags:
    - testing
  script:
    - /node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx .

bump:
  stage: build
  tags: 
    - deploy
  script:
    - grunt bump
  only:
    - master
    - /^Merge .*$/

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  only:
    - master
    - tags
    - /^Release .*$/

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - cd /home/ubuntu
    - docker-compose up -d
  only:
    - master
    - tags
    - /^Release .*$/
```

Comment: So you want it to be run for the tag after the commit or do you want it to run on a branch when you open a merge request?

Comment: After the commit...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to execute jobs `only/except` based on the predefined gitlab variable `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`.
See [gitlab ci reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables).
Check also the [docu](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#environment-variables-expressions) on how variable expressions are handled.

```
commit_message_has_release_job:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^Release .*$/
  [...]
```

It is also possible to filter for [merge_requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic).

```
merge_request_job:
  only:
    - merge_requests
  [...]
```

Combining multiple cases of `only/except` may not work as you might expect it. The list does not work connected with `AND`, but `OR`. Also, it is not 100% sure that a leading `only` followed by an `except` works as you expect it. So a simple workaround would be something like this:

```
merge_reqeuest_to_master_job:
  only:
    - merge_requests
  before_script:
    - if [[ $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "master" ]]; exit 0 ; fi
```

Since the variable `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` is just set, if the pipeline is for a merge request, you could just do:

```
merge_reqeuest_to_master_job:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
```

However, the feature ["CI variable expression conjunction/disjunction"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/27925) is implemented since 12.0.

```
merge_reqeuest_to_master_job:
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

To your other remarks:

- If a single job of a stage fails, by default no jobs from the following stages are started automatically (if you do not  `allow_failure: true` or `when: on_failure`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to trigger pipeline with the specific commit message, for that we can use regexp

For me it works with the following,

```
install_nodemodules:
stage: install
script:
    - npm install
artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
only:
    variables:
         - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /Release/
```

In each stage you need to specify this condition to execute the stage when the Commit message equals to Release